Multiple @RequestPart in Spring FeignClient causing "Required part not present"
I am writing a server application that should forward a file and upload it to another server.
front-end ---> forwarder ---> backend
The forwarder received the file from the frontend successfully. But when I try to forward it, I get an error:
@Autowired
private BackendFeignClient backend;

public ResponseEntity<FileMetadataOutDTO> forward(FileMetadataInDTO fileMetadataInDTO, MultipartFile file, String jwtToken)
{
    return backend.save(fileMetadataInDTO, file, jwtToken);
}

The feign client looks like this:
@FeignClient(
        name = "file-upload-client", url = "${manager.root.uri}", configuration = BackendFeignClient.MultipartSupportConfig.class)
public interface BackendFeignClient
{
    @PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<FileMetadataOutDTO> save(
            @RequestPart("fileMetadataInDTO") FileMetadataInDTO fileMetadataInDTO,
            @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file,
            @RequestHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION) String jwtToken);

    public class MultipartSupportConfig {
        @Autowired
        private ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters> messageConverters;

        @Bean
        public Encoder feignFormEncoder () {
            return new SpringFormEncoder(new SpringEncoder(messageConverters));
        }
    }
}

The backend, just like the forwarder, accepts the file and metadata like this:
@PostMapping(consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public FileMetadataOutDTO save(
        @Valid @RequestPart(value = "fileMetadataInDTO") FileMetadataInDTO fileMetadataInDTO,
        @RequestPart(value = "file", required = true) MultipartFile file)
{
    return fileService.save(calibrationCertificateInDTO, file);
}

Unfortunately, I get this error:
Converted error json {
  "type" : "about:blank",
  "title" : "Bad Request",
  "status" : 400,
  "detail" : "Required part 'fileMetadataInDTO' is not present.",
  "instance" : "/api/v1/upload"
}

I tried adding MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE , but then the body could not be encoded.
consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE }

I also added those dependencies:
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.openfeign.form</groupId>
    <artifactId>feign-form</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.openfeign.form</groupId>
    <artifactId>feign-form-spring</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
</dependency>

But it didn't help.

At first glance I would say that FileMetadataInDTO isn't fileMetadataInDTO the names are different.

You are right. This was a small mistake of mine while composing the question. In the codes its correct. I corrected it.

So this isn't the actual code but a dumbed down version of it?

I had a similar issue, where I needed to send
@PostMapping(value = "/save", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
Response save(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile multipartFile,
              @RequestPart("createRequest") CreateRequest createRequest); 

so basically you need to define bean JsonFormWriter in your feign client's configuration.
public class FeignClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    JsonFormWriter jsonFormWriter() {
        return new JsonFormWriter();
    }
}

This could also help: Feign multipart with Json request part
